# Selenium adds hash to findElement

Tags: javascript, java, maven, selenium

I'm writting a code in Selenium Webdriver. I have to click the button with HTML code is

`<input id="aui_3_4_0_1_300" class="aui-button-input aui-button-input-submit" type="submit">`

My code then is as simply as following

`driver.findElement(By.id("aui_3_4_0_1_300")).click();`

But when I'm running a code (using Maven), I got an information

`Unable to locate element: #aui_3_4_0_1_300`

I got also this problem with

`driver.findElement(By.id("_58_login")).clear();`

and also got the `Unable to locate element: #_58_login`, but I thought it was a problem with underscores. (I solved it by adding `synchronized(driver) {driver.wait(1000);}` before that line and it works).

Why compiler added the hash `#`?

Comment: that is only suggestion, that you are locating by ID. In CSS locate of element by ID is done by `#ID {...}`

Comment: There is no element with that id in your dom. The `#` is not added, it is just part of the message.

Comment: Ooops, copied incorrect line, a typo occured ;) thanks for noticitng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler adds nothing to your selector- `"#"` just stands for `id` in `CSS` as well as `"."` stands for class name.

So `By.id("aui_3_4_0_1_300")` is the same as `By.cssSelector("#aui_3_4_0_1_300")` and

`By.className("aui-button-input")` is the same as `By.cssSelector(".aui-button-input")`

It seems that there is a timing issue- required element generated dynamically, so you need to wait until it present in `DOM`:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.id("aui_3_4_0_1_300"))).click();
```

If `id` value `"aui_3_4_0_1_300"` is not constant you might need to match element by patrial `id` value (starting characters):

```
wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[id^='aui_']"))).click();
```

or just use another elements' attribute:

```
wait.until(elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("input[type='submit']"))).click();
```

Comment: id value is constant, so that's not the problem. I used a workaround by using `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='submit']"));` for button and `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='_58_login']"))`. I was just curious why I got in error message was #. Your answer solve my question, thank you :)